# should I appove edits which "correct" the answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

The question is about this requested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4042746  (about this answer: [Run videolan from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403556/run-videolan-from-browser/21478435#21478435)) ....

1. "Dr. Molle" gave an answer
2. "Rorro" commented saying it worked mostly, but there was a problem
3. Molle edited answer
4. Rorro tested the new answer, found it didn't work at all, and requested to revert the answer back.

I would have accepted the requested edit. Is that a fine idea? Or should "corrective" edits be left to poster to make? (someone else rejected edits before I approved them).

multiple people accepted it, while multiple also rejected. What guidelines should I use?

Comment: One thought I had: it was to Rorro himself that the updated answer was made for. Therefore, shouldn't Rorro have sensible rights to "reject" that newer answer as not sufficient?

Comment: ^he could reject the answer by unaccepting it, then the answerer might be more likely to revert the post himself.

Comment: @OGHaza, but the answerer often don't have the time or motivation to ever go back and re-context switch to the question and retest an answer and change it. So let the one who is motivated and able to truly test the answers make edits like that.

Comment: FWIW often people are more lenient with edits by a question asker - that is if they take the time to notice who they are. A 100 rep user doing a code edit on a 50k user's post is never going to have much chance. The fact is, the edit probably wasn't rejected because anyone doesn't want the OP reverting an answer, it was probably because he appears to be "fixing" someone else's code.